# asp.net front end validation - only lower values allowed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, validation, gridview, frontend

I am editing a field in gridview and would like that the edited value not be allowed to be greater than the old value?

is there a front end validation for this? so as to not use a javascript popup

Thanks

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FC Amount">             
    <ItemTemplate>   
        <asp:Label ID="FCLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FC AMOUNT") %>'></asp:Label>         
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>                    
        <asp:TextBox ID="FCTextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FC AMOUNT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) control:

Add hidden with old value, and compare its value with new one. Or set `ValueToCompare` property:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FC Amount">             
    <ItemTemplate>   
        <asp:Label ID="FCLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FC AMOUNT") %>'></asp:Label>         
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>                    
        <asp:TextBox ID="FCTextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FC AMOUNT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CompareValidator 
    ID="cmpAmount" 
    runat="server" 
    ValueToCompare='<%# Eval("FC AMOUNT") %>'
    ControlToValidate="FCTextBox1"
    Type="Double"
    Operator="LessThanEqual" /> 

    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[How to: Validate Against a Specific Value for ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e303tf05.aspx)
[CompareValidator.Operator Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.operator.aspx)

Comment: @Karl Added the example and link for more documentation. I think you should read that article.

Comment: its giving me a runtime error
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to find control id 'hdnOldValue' referenced by the 'ControlToCompare' property of 'cmpAmount'.

Comment: @Karl This is because the hidden field is in template< and had dynamical ID. I've provided less complex solution.

Comment: works fine :) except its the other way round, the user cannot enter lager values, do i just need to change the operator? THANKS

Comment: @Karl Well, yes, you should change it. Updated the answer and provided the link to the property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 <asp:CompareValidator 
        ID="cval1" 
        runat="server" 
        ValueToCompare='<%#Eval("OldValue") %>'
        ControlToValidate="FCTextBox1"
        Type="Integer"
        Operator="GreaterThanEqual" />
```

Comment: where must i put this code? its telling me Parser Error Message: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. 'asp:CompareValidator' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator'.